# html5 canvas: How do I draw a really long wave/curve and get the bounds from it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to draw a really long wave/curve. Perhaps over 10000px in width. The curve is more like a path with a car in the center of the path. So when the car hit the side of the path, it will detect the collision.

I have experiment with beizer curve. However it doesn't satisfy my need because I can only curve it to one side.

Should I just draw the whole path with many beizer curves?

How can I detect the collision or getting the bounds of the curve?

Any advice would be grateful. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that receives a x coordinate as argument and returns the y coordinate describing your curve. To detect collision pass the x coordinate of your object to the function and compare the y coordinate returned by the function with the y coordinate of your object.

You should be able to use `BezierCurveTo` and `quadraticCurveTo` to draw your curve.